# Scrape "data-price" from html source-code

Tags: python, web-scraping

For a projekt at my University, I want to scrape a price.
The element data-price includes the price.

My first Try:

```
import requests
import bs4
import lxml
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get('...').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify())


summary = soup.find('div', class_='data-price')
print(summary.prettify())
```

The Sourcecode:

```
div class="c-price-b...ice-block" id="..." data-product-name="Apple&Tree" data-price="xxx" data-categories="ddd" " data-qa="price-block"
```

Is there any possibility to extract the price?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depends if it is returned in the response from requests. You can try an attribute selector

```
soup.select_one('[data-product-name="Apple&Tree"]')['data-price']
```

I would prefer to try and use class but I cannot see what the proper class was.

By using `data-product-name="Apple&Tree"`  with `select_one` I am assuming the first match for that attribute = value specification is the desired one. `select` can be used to return a list.